# Can a Space Combat action get more than +60 bonus?

Tags: combat, rogue-trader, non-combat

The rules describing "normal" combat say

> If a situation calls for two or more bonuses or penalties,
>   simply combine all modifiers together and apply the total to
>   the appropriate Characteristic.
>
> The maximum total bonus that can be applied to a test
>   is +60. Conversely, the maximum total penalty that can be
>   applied to a test is –60.

Does this rule apply to Space Combat (aka Ship to Ship combat)? Similarly, does it also apply to non-combat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Space Combat is still a combat encounter using Characteristic and Skill Tests -- just on a different playing field. The initiative is different and the question "***what*** action do I take?" is brought to the foreground, but the core rules of ***how*** they are performed remains the same. During this combat, the character's personal characteristics are still being tested (i.e. Firing the cannons of the ship is a *Ballistic Test* by the character directing the cannons // The pilot usually has to make a *Pilot (Space Craft)* Skill Test to fly the ship in advanced ways). The same restrictions on these tests apply: no more than a +/- 60 modifier to any test.

You've already quoted the most crucial part of this.

> The ***maximum total bonus*** that can be applied to ***a test*** is +60. Conversely, the ***maximum total penalty*** that can be applied to ***a test*** is –60.
>   *~Rogue Trader Core Handbook: Page 244*

There is, of course, also these:

> The maximum modifier that can be applied to a Skill Test or Characteristic Test is +60 or –60. *~Deathwatch, Final Sanction: Page 10*
>
> The maximum modifier that can be applied to a Skill Test or Characteristic Test is +60 or –60. *~Black Crusade, Broken Chains: Page 10*
>
> The maximum modifier that can be applied to a Skill Test or Characteristic Test is +60 or –60. *~Only War, Eleventh Hour: Page 10*

There isn't much room for interpretation here. Fantasy Flight Games has kept this core mechanic constant throughout their Warhammer 40k titles (The only exception to this ***may*** be *Dark Heresy 2nd Edition*. I haven't gotten the chance to look through it yet, so I can't be 100% sure), thus if playing by RAW then yes, 60 is the limit in either direction.

The only way out of this I can see would be what Skeith said earlier -- using a Fate Point to get +10 extra.

Comment: However, acquisition tests can get +/-70 modifier (page 272 of the core rulebook). That's why I'm asking... It only states than when specifically referring to the ground combat and that rule is never again mentioned in the entire book.

Comment: True, however an Acquisition Test is neither a Characteristic nor Skill Test. It is a completely separate matter that uses different stats. When dealing with Characteristic or Skill Tests, the modifier only goes to +/- 60. This is why it applies to Space Combat as well; every Test is a Characteristic or Skill Test.

Comment: However, nowhere in the rules explaining Characteristic tests says that the modifiers can only get +/-60... I know that there says "tests", and as far as I'm concerned I'll interpret that it means EVERY test, BUT it's still a bit confusing that this somewhat important piece of information is only mentioned once in the book, and in a section that is not the specific section that explains the rules to which this refers.

Comment: Well, as I've said, Space combat is *still* combat that uses Characteristic and Skill Tests to function, thus that section of the book applies to space combat as well if playing by RAW; and as I've pointed out, it is a core mechanic of the game that has carried itself throughout all FFG's Warhammer 40k titles. Not much room for interpretation.

However if you still have doubts, you can contact FFG's themselves through their "Rules Question form" on their website at the following link:
https://www.fantasyflightgames.com/en/contact/rules/
Please let us know if they give you a different answer.

Answer (score 0):

No you can never get more that a + or - 60 modifier on any test in any of the fantasy flight Warhammer 40k games.

In Deathwatch you can use fate to increase a roll by 10 gettign in effect a +70 but i dont think you get fate points in rogue trader

Comment: You have fate points in RT. Where in the rules says no test can have more than +60 modifier in any test? (I'm not telling you a liar, I just can't find it)